# Asymptotic expansion of $(\sin x)^x$ $(x\to0^+)$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Determine the asymptotic expansion of $(\sin x)^x$ as $x\to0^+$. It is a question in my textbook, and I cannot find out how to calculate it.
How can I solve this? The answer of the textbook is
$$1+x\log x+\frac12\left(x^2 (\log x)^2\right)+o\!\left(x^2 (\log x)^2\right).$$

Comment: Some hints: $$
x\log (\sin x) = x\log (x - x^3 /6 +  \ldots ) = x\log x + x\log (1 - x^2 /6 +  \ldots ) = x\log x + \mathcal{O}(x^3 ) \\= x\log x + o(x^2 \log ^2 x)
$$ as $x\to 0^+$. Then $$
(\sin x)^x  = \exp (x\log (\sin x)) = \exp (x\log x)\exp (o(x^2 \log ^2 x))
$$ as $x\to 0^+$. Now use the power series of $\exp(w)$ an replace $w$ with the appropriate quantities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)= (\sin x)^x$ and $g(x) = \log f(x)$

Then $$g(x) = x \log(\sin(x)) = x \log (x + o(x^2)) = x \log (x(1 + o(x))\\
=x\log x +x \log(1+ o(x))\\
= x\log x +o(x^2) $$

Hence $g(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$

And $$f(x) = e^{g(x)} = 1 + g(x) + \frac{1}{2}g(x)^2 + o(g(x)^2) = \\
1 + x\log x + \frac12 (x \log x)^2 + o((x \log x)^2)+o(x^2)=\\
1 + x\log x + \frac12 (x \log x)^2 + o((x \log x)^2)
$$